# DROP Syntax error in SQLiteManager

Tags: ios, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have downloaded sqlite manager app in Firefox browser and open sqlite manager app.

1) Created database named **DBSQLTEST**.

2) Created table named **SQLTEST** contain has threes fields are **SLNO**, **NAME** and **AGE**

3) Inserted new records

But i want remove a ‘**AGE**’ column in sqltest table

i using sql command like below

**ALTER TABLE SQLTEST DROP COLUMN AGE**

SQLiteManager message says

**SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: ALTER TABLE SQLTEST DROP COLUMN AGE [ near "DROP": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]**

What is error that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sqlite does not support `DROP COLUMN` in `ALTER TABLE`. You can only rename tables and add columns.

Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

If you need to remove columns, create a new table, copy the data there, drop the old table and rename the table to its intented name.

Comment: how we can to remove a column in table?

Comment: It seems sqlite now does support DROP COLUMN, but it's somewhat limited. It's explained on the page you linked (probably updated).

Comment: For completion: https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html#altertabdropcol SQLite 3.35.0 introduced support for `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN`.

Answer (score 8):

[SQLite does not fully support `ALTER TABLE` statements](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). You can only rename table, or add columns.

If you want to drop a column, your best option is to create a new table without the column, and to drop the old table in order to rename the new one.

For example, suppose you have a table named "t1" with columns names "a", "b", and "c" and that you want to delete column "c" from this table. The following steps illustrate how this could be done:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1;
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup;
COMMIT;
```

Credits to Benoit.

Answer (score 3):

Create a table

**CREATE TABLE SQLTEST ("SLNO" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"NAME" TEXT,AGE INTEGER)**

If want to remove a column

**ALTER TABLE SQLTEST RENAME TO SQLTESTCOPY**

**CREATE TABLE SQLTEST ("SLNO" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"NAME" TEXT)**

**INSERT INTO SQLTEST"SELECT "SLNO","NAME" FROM SQLTESTCOPY**

**DROP TABLE SQLTESTCOPY**

easy.